# Autodesk Forge Viewer get bucket files to display multiple views

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Does anyone know if it is possible to get all the bucket files data in some kind of array or similiar? I'm thinking of building a viewer where you can load a different view, containing a different model, when the user clicks on the desired model (thumbnail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if I do not misunderstand your requirement. You can get all your buckets by [GET buckets API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET/), you will get an bucket array like this:

```js
{
    "items": [
        {
            "bucketKey": "mybucket1",
            "createdDate": 1508056179005,
            "policyKey": "persistent"
        },
        {
            "bucketKey": "mybucket2",
            "createdDate": 1502411682779,
            "policyKey": "transient"
        },
        {
            "bucketKey": "mybucket3",
            "createdDate": 1502420840319,
            "policyKey": "transient"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can iterate all these buckets to get all the files under each bucket by [GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/), it will provide you an array of items like this:

```js
{
    "items": [
        {
            "bucketKey": "mybucket1",
            "objectKey": "mytestbim1.rvt",
            "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket1/mytestbim1.rvt",
            "sha1": "248205b7609ca95c04e4d60fee2ad7b6bd9a2uy2",
            "size": 17113088,
            "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket1/objects/mytestbim1.rvt"
        },
        {
            "bucketKey": "mybucket1",
            "objectKey": "mytestbim2.rvt",
            "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket1/mytestbim2.rvt",
            "sha1": "248205b7609ca95c04e4d60fee2ad7b6bd8a2322",
            "size": 17113088,
            "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket1/objects/mytestbim2.rvt"
        }        
    ]
}
```

The most important value is the "**objectId**", it will be the **urn** after base64 encoded, you can get all the derivative with this **urn**, and also you can load the **urn** in Forge Viewer after it's translated to SVF.

We have an code example of [Forge Node.js Boilers](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs), and you can check the project 5 to see if that is something you are interested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok yes, thanks for that! :-) Is there a way to base64 encode the ObjectID right away? I mean so that I can put all urn's into an array and pass them to a list of anchors so that I can re-initialize the viewer each time I click on the single anchor?

Comment: That depends on which language you are using, for example, with node.js, you can use something like this: > console.log(new Buffer("Hello World").toString('base64'));
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
> console.log(new Buffer("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=", 'base64').toString('ascii'))
Hello World         there should be different libraries for different language if you search.